# Validate JWT from Microsoft using .Net Core C#

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, jwt, .net-core

I have a .Net Core app, which receive JWT token from Microsoft (MS is used as OAuth server). I have next settings at MS side:

- App ID: UUID
- Password (generated by MS)
- Private key (protected by password provided by me)

I receive it as string and convert to `JwtSecurityToken`, and I see my name, email and all other stuff...

**Question**: how can I check this token was actually issued by MS for my app? I'm pretty sure I have to use `ValidateToken(string token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken)` but looks like I cannot do `TokenValidationParameters` right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstand you, but if the token was issued from MS, the token should not need validation in the client.

You should just use this token as a black box, and the server will validate the token during the clients requests. If MS used a symmetric key for signing, they would keep the key hidden and you can never validate the token in the client. With an asymmetric key, you could do validation but only if you have the public part of the key.

You can use the info in the JWT if it is not encrypted, but that is on your own risk. It may be manipulated, and the server that issue the JWT may change the content or structure of the JSON object inside, change from signed JWT's to encrypted JWTs or change it to a random token *without breaking your contract*, so your app should probably not rely on that content.

Comment: Token is issued from MS, but I will not my use it to call MS services. I just check if name/email are correct and then provide access to my own system. So I need to check not only name/password, but if this token is actually come from MS

Comment: Didn't you receive it from MS? Then it is of course valid. Else you can use it to try to access an MS api that this JWT is suppose give access to. If the call succeed the JWT is valid, else not. I think you are designing your authentication based on wrong assumptions. As i described in my answer, you can not trust the content in the JWT to be accessible and not changing over time. If you want your user to get access in your service based on MS login, maybe there is an oAuth2 service at MS that you can use?

Comment: Yeah, I received it from MS, but on client-side with JS. I thought I can use it as request parameter to call my "protected parts" on server-side. So I need to check if JWT is not issued by someone who is not MS.
Maybe, I need to rethink all my "reinvented security flow"

Comment: I think so too, since you don't have the signing key not the option to control who get access to your system. Good luck